# OAuth2 API access from a command line tool to extract data records

Tags: c#, .net, api, oauth-2.0

Can anyone give an idea of how and where I might start to connect to an API using OAuth2?

I have a clientID and secret etc. All I am trying to do is access some of our company records through an API.

I am struggling to work out to do this in .NET in a console app, and even if it's possible?

Any advice on libraries I can use as a wrapper or a start to get me going would be appreciated. I am out of my depth a little on this one having never done it before. I have done a pluralsight course on OAuth2 and have a beginners understanding of how it works, but I am struggling how to get this implemented into a console app and cannot seem to find anything relevant on Github or here on S.O.

My expected workflow is something like this:
(Please correct me if anything here looks wrong)

- Start console app
- App either stores or asks for ClientID and secret
- Diverts to web login for authorisation
- App handles authentication and tokens
- App calls APIs as required and inserts data into our own database

Any help would be great. Thank you.

Comment: a good start is to read some tutorials. You will need to use an http client such as HttpClient, RestSharp ..etc. if the server uses OpenId or IdentityServer then you need to read more about them and how to work with them as well.

Comment: What APIs are you trying to access?

Comment: Xero and WorkFlowMax API's. I have found an app provided by them that allows you to get a token and use it in Postman. But that is as far as I have gotten so far.